# Expanding the Gravity Forms e-commerce features

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am looking to create a "chinese auction" website.  This is a method of fundraising where prizes are auctioned off and people purchase tickets on the website and put them towards a prize(s). Gravity Forms has the capability to sell products and tickets which I am familiar with.  I'm just looking for some direction on how to integrate the process of buying tickets and applying them towards a prize.

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to create the "tickets" using the GF Coupon Add-on and my [Creating Coupons for GF Coupons Add-on with Gravity Forms](http://gravitywiz.com/creating-coupons-for-gf-coupons-add-on-with-gravity-forms/) snippet.

With this snippet, you can easily create a coupon code for each "ticket" which the user could then apply on subsequent submissions to get the prizes.

I'll admit, there might some oddness with this approach if tickets have no monetary value associated but you might be able to obscure some of that oddness via CSS to hide totals and pricing output.

**--- Updated: Jan 30th, 2015 ---**

I'm happy to elaborate on this idea. I don't think that this is the *best* solution but it is *a solution* available with existing code.

First, [here's a demo](http://demos.gravitywiz.com/gw-raffle/) of what the form might look like.

- We use a Product field to hold the products available for the raffle. Each product costs a minimum of $1 (i.e. 1 ticket).
- We use a Total field to calculate how many tickets are required.
- We use a Coupon field to calculate allow the user to enter their "tickets" towards the selected product.

When an appropriate amount of tickets have been entered, the submit button appears.

**Shortcomings**

- This only works if the form is dedicated to the raffle ticket exchange. If you need to use the product fields for any other purpose, this solution will not work.
- The required tickets and coupon codes are currently formatted in dollars. Obviously, their intended purpose is to work in units of money not tickets. This could be fixed with additional code.

**How do I set this up?**

You'll need one form to generate a coupon. You can use custom code or [GP Unique ID](http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-unique-id/) to generate a unique code and [this snippet](http://gravitywiz.com/creating-coupons-for-gf-coupons-add-on-with-gravity-forms/) to create a coupon (i.e. ticket) based on that unique code.

You'll also need a second form where the user can actually use their tickets to purchase items. See the field instructions above on how to configure this form.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but tickets have to be bought.  People need to be able to apply multiple tickets towards a prize.

Comment: Can you explain this approach better?  I'm not sure I get it.  This needs to function like a raffle, except that the tickets are being used towards prizes.

Comment: Just updated my original answer with more details and a [demo](http://demos.gravitywiz.com/gw-raffle/).